# Baby Rudin (2.12) Request for Clarification

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis (1976) by Walter Rudin specifically, chapter $2$ theorem $2.12$, the theorem states the following :

> **Theorem 2.12** : Let $\{E_{n}\}$, $n=1,2,3...$, be a *sequence of countable sets* , and put : $$  S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n} $$ Then
> $S$ is countable.

$$
$$
*Q1*) What is the difference between the **union of countable sets** and the **union of a sequence of countable sets**? $$
$$
*Q2*) I did not quite understand the strategy of the proof Rudin presented due to the fact that I am trying to study analysis by myself which might have been a bad idea. $$
$$
On a side note, I hope I am not the only person who finds the notation used to represent a sequence to be inappropriate.

Comment: the only bad idea, in studying analysis, rests on the fact of using only one book

Comment: I agree, sometimes I question how Rudin came up with a lot of formulas without showing us how he built them from scratch. I am trying to refer to "T.M. Apostl's Real Analysis" and "Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis"

Comment: Oh, Abbott's book!  That is another recommendation I should have made [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785764/difficulty-understanding-rudins-example-2-10b#comment7798352_3786348).  Abbott's book is great!

Comment: yep I agree, Abbott's book is a great book to understand analysis but I always feel like Rudin's book is the one that needs to be mastered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is to list all elements while making sure that 'all bases are covered'.

You organize and layout the elements on paper,

[image]

Note that while there is no bottom or right edge for this 'matrix picture', you can 'cross stuff out' by traversing from the left edge to the top edge using diagonals.

The elements in set $E_n$ are listed out in row $n$, with the first subscript $n$ of  $x_{(n,k)}$ used for the set and the second subscript $k$ used for the enumeration of that set.

Then as Rudin crosses out the diagonals all elements will be crossed out. Notice that the third diagonal,

$\quad x_{(3,1)},x_{(2,2)},x_{(1,3)}$

'takes out' the entries where the subscripts for $x_{(n,k)}$ add up to $4$,

$\quad n + k = 4$

The $t^{th}$ diagonal takes out the $n + k = t + 1$ tabularly arranged elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.